# Runtime Error on CodeChef: SIGSEGV - CodeChef

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am solving this question: https://www.codechef.com/LTIME83B/problems/FFL

But in this I am getting `RE (SIGSEGV)`. I do not get, why am I getting that?

I don't think I have exceeded the limit of the array.

Then why I am getting this error?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <vector>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    cout.tie(NULL);

    ll t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        ll n, s;
        cin >> n >> s;
        s = 100 - s;
        ll i, a[n], k;
        vector<ll> g1;
        vector<ll> g2;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cin >> a[i];
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cin >> k;
            if (k == 0)
            {
                g1.push_back(a[i]);
            }
            if (k == 1)
            {
                g2.push_back(a[i]);
            }
        }
        ll o = *min_element(g1.begin(), g1.end());
        ll p = *min_element(g2.begin(), g2.end());
        if (s >= o + p)
        {
            cout << "yes" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "no"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `long long a[n]` is not valid in C++. `n` must be a compile time constant.

Comment: @S.M. I guess he takes in the value of `n` using `cin`.

Comment: @sbak Accept the answer if the doubt is resolved so that the question is marked solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not handling the case where all available players are either defenders or attackers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <vector>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    cout.tie(NULL);

    ll t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        ll n, s;
        cin >> n >> s;
        s = 100 - s;
        ll i, a[n], k;
        vector<ll> g1;
        vector<ll> g2;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cin >> a[i];
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cin >> k;
            if (k == 0)
            {
                g1.push_back(a[i]);
            }
            if (k == 1)
            {
                g2.push_back(a[i]);
            }
        }
        if(g1.size() == 0 || g2.size() == 0){
            cout<<"no\n";
            continue;
        }
        ll o = *min_element(g1.begin(), g1.end());
        ll p = *min_element(g2.begin(), g2.end());
        if (s >= o + p)
        {
            cout << "yes" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "no"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Try submitting this code.